# How can I get debugging output from IE 9?

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to make a website that uses the <canvas> element and Javascript to learn some new things.

It works properly inside of Chrome and Firefox, but Internet Explorer 9 simply hangs on it. Neither Chrome nor Firefox give me any sort of error output in their consoles and IE9 just crashes without actually giving any debug output.

Is there a way to get a debug dump or attach a debugger to IE9 so that I can figure out why my page is crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the [console tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705.aspx#_Console_tab).  I wouldn't stress if you can't get your app to run in ie9 as it's only in beta.  Golf clap for trying to stay ahead of the browser version curve, though.

Answer (score 0):

Although IE9 is currently in beta, if you're serious about developing IE9 applications, [try out the latest Platform Preview](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/) (Currently Platform Preview 5).  The platform previews are development releases that give you a more up-to-date version of the browser (even past the Beta).  While these are not production ready, they do include more fixes and HTML5 standard implementations with each release.  Give the latest one a try.